# How to make separate working directories for separate branches using TFS Git?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have (2) separate branches in a `TFS` managed `Git` repository that I'm working with in `VS.NET 2013` that are quite a bit different (i.e. solution and project structure are different during major upgrade process). I notice that if I have Windows Explorer opened and *switch* between the repositories, the working directory is automatically updated and restructured with the new files.

This is nice because seamlessly `Git` will bring into the working directory all of the current files for the active branch I selected. However what I really need is for *separate* working directories so I can see all of the project files for both branches at the same time. This as opposed to using the same directory that's being essentially overwritten each time I change branches.

I have looked at every 'right-click' or 'settings' option available in the IDE and can't seem to find a way to assign separate directories for each branch. How can I assign different working directories to *separate* `Git` branches using `VS.NET 2013`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot. Unlike TFVC (where branches exist inside the path space of the repository), in Git, branches exist at the repository level.

You should clone the repository a second time, to a second location, and you can keep each local repository checked out to a different branch.

Comment: I wondered if cloning to a separate directory was the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not planning on committing, you can check out a commit to a different directory. (You could commit also, but that will make things really confusing, so do not do that.)

```
git checkout <branch-1>
cd <path/to/other/dir>
git --git-dir=<path/to/repository/.git>  checkout <branch-1>
cd <path/to/repository>
git c
git checkout <branch-2>
```

The checkout command **does** change the branch in the actual repository, so it must be executed before checking out the repository branch.

**EDIT: Better Alternative**

```
 git checkout <branch-1>
 git --work-tree=../test2 co HEAD
 git checkout <branch-2>
```

This is better for because

- there are much fewer steps
- it is safer because you are not checking out a different commit into the the other directory

There may still be issues when checking out a second time to the alternate directory. You can just delete it and start over since you are using it as view-only.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from git version 2.6.0 you can use the `git worktree` command to create a separate worktree to have work in parallel.

```
git checkout branch1
// working on branch1
git worktreee add ../branch2-workspace branch2
cd ../branch2-workspace
//working on branch2
```

when you are done with the folder, just delete it, and run `git worktree prune`